# В переменной типа long не помещается выражение 300*300

Tags: c, arduino, преобразование

В языке ардуино, если писать

```
long A = 90000;
Serial.println(A);
```

то все правильно работает, но если писать

```
long A = 300*300;
Serial.println(A);
```

то выводит 24464. И даже если писать

```
Serial.println(300*300);
```

то результат тот же. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А может быть, на вашей платформе `int` 16-битный? 90000 - 24464 = 65536.

Comment: @VladD int 16 битный для ардуино по умолчанию, проверял оператором sizeof. Правильно ли я понял, что результат вырожения должен вмещатся в int? Просто это функцианирует так же, даже если присваивать переменному типа float или double.

Comment: Просто результатом умножения `int` на `int` является именно `int`, так что если он не помещается в `int`, происходит отбрасывание старших байт. А константа 90000, как указано в ответе, трактуется сразу как `long`.

Comment: @VladD Спасибо, теперь все ясно

Comment: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Похоже, что выражение

```
long A = 300*300;
         ^^^^^^^^
```

вычисляется, как имеющее тип `int`, и объект типа `int` не может вместить в себя результирующее значение.

Запишите следующим образом

```
long A = ( long )300*300;
```

или

```
long A = 300l*300l;
```

Что касается данной инициализации

```
long A = 90000;
```

то для целочисленного литерала компилятор определяет тот целочисленный тип, который может вместить в себя данное значение.

Согласно стандарту C (6.4.4.1 Integer constants)

> 5 The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding
>   list in which its value can be represented

И далее в таблице указывается, что когда литерал не имеет суффикса, то последовательно подбирается тип литерала в порядке `int`, `long int`, `long long int`.

Comment: Странно, что при этом `long A = 90000;` компилируется как будто 90000 влазит в `int`.

Comment: @VladD Компилятор определяет для литерала подходящий тип. Это не обязательно будет тип int.

Comment: Хм, а это по стандарту?

Comment: @VladD Я отобразил это в своем ответе.

Comment: Ого, круто, не знал, спасибо!